# How do I get part flat on z axis?

Tags: workflow

When I start blender the z axis is going through the center of my part. I need the bottom of the part to be flat with the z axis. I have watch dozens of videos and nobody covers this because when they start blender their part is the way its supposed to be. [image]

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. What do you mean by "center of my part"? What is part? Your Z-Axis (Blue) isn't showing right now. Maybe include an image of the state you want it to be. Or link one of the videos you mentioned.

Comment: Ok I got my axis mixed up. The part bottom needs to be flat with the y and x axis.

Comment: I guess Pascal Sommer's answer is useful to you, mark his answer as accepted, if this answers your question. Also please edit your question (x and y axis), so it turns out clear in search results.

Comment: Yes that worked ! Thanks Pascal ! And yes I will never use anything below ground plane as I'm going to be using this for 3d printing. Is there anyway to take out all those video controls I will never use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want the bottom of the cube to be at z height zero.

You can edit the cube in edit mode (press <kbd>tab</kbd>), select all the vertecies (by pressing <kbd>a</kbd>) and then move them up by 1 (<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>).

After leaving edit mode again, you can set this scene to be the default scene when you open a new file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>. If you open a new file now with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>, you will find that the bottom of the cube is aligned to z=0.